# How to create ionic blank app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi i am new in cordova ionic i want to create blank app.created that, but where i need to write the controllers

```
run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
```

this is the app.js
i completed a side menu app using ionic in that i wrote the controller in controller.js. but in blank where i need to write?

Comment: can  you please see again your question. I read several times it and it is totally unclear for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new controllers.js and write the controllers code in that file